# Авто подстановка символов в TextField android

Tags: android, jtextfield

Здравствуйте. Возникла потребность реализовать поле для ввода даты в формате Мм/Гг. Подскажите как сделать так, что бы символ "/" сам вставлялся между ММ и ГГ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а почему не использовать стандартный компонент [Pickers](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)?

Comment: Спасибо. Я Думал о нем... Но полей для ввода несколько, и решил что это будет выглядеть немного некрасиво.

А там разве можно показать диалог только ММ\ГГ ? выбор числа вообще не нужен)

Comment: ну тогда можно воспользоваться кастомными виджетами. Просмотрите внимательно эту тему на [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122929/how-to-display-date-picker-for-android-with-only-month-and-year-fields).